# Changing css property via jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve here is when I hover over the link it would turn green.

What is exactly wrong with this code:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").hover(function() {
     $(this).css({"background-color": "green;"});
     });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: You added a semi-colon after `green`. This is incorrect css value

Comment: do you know that on mouseleave the anchor will still be green? Just asking. Otherwise such things should be handled by CSS, not JS

Comment: Dammit ! XD One stupid semicolon. It works now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the semicolon after `green;`, that works in CSS, but not in javascript, which expects a color only, no semicolon.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").hover(function() {
         $(this).css({"background-color": "green"});
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery having .css() function which will allow you to change CSS property or any DOM Element on document.

**Single Property Example:**

```
jQuery(Selector).css("PropertyName", "Value");
```

**Multiple Property Example:**

```
jQuery(Selector).css({"PropertyName1": "Value1", "PropertyName2": "Value2"});
```

e.g.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).css("background-color", "green");
    });
});
```